# docker-compose: CMD variable substitution

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I am building a new Docker image but my CMD command with variable substitution does not work.

**I know that I need to turn on the interpreter with `-c` like this:**

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "hello.sh $VARIABLE"]
```

**But my use case is different because I need to execute something with `sudo`:**

```
CMD ["sudo", "-u", "oracle", "$ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/$DOMAIN_NAME/startWebLogic.sh"]
```

**This works properly:**

```
CMD $ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/$DOMAIN_NAME/startWebLogic.sh
```

Ho to make it works with `sudo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
CMD ["sudo", "-E", "-u", "oracle", "sh", "-c", "\"$ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/$DOMAIN_NAME/startWebLogic.sh\""]
```

By default `sudo` starts a new environment. To have `sudo` preserve the environment you need to pass `-E` option.

Then to have `$variables` expand, you need to run it under a shell, so they can expand. But then to protect against word splitting shell expansion I think you have to quote the variables expansions, thus the additional `\"`.

Maybe this would be easier and also work:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "sudo -u oracle \"$ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/$DOMAIN_NAME/startWebLogic.sh\""]
```

But in docker I think it's preferable to just set the user:

```
USER oracle
CMD $ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/$DOMAIN_NAME/startWebLogic.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same thing, just with `sudo` in front:

```
CMD ["sudo", "-u", "oracle", "sh", "-c", "hello.sh $VARIABLE"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. This is the result: `weblogic-admin-server      | sh: /user_projects/domains//startWebLogic.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: When I start the container with docker-compose.